# How to understand cudaStreamQuery behavior when querying default stream?

Tags: cuda

From [CUDA manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g2021adeb17905c7ec2a3c1bf125c5435), I know `cudaStreamQuery` operates on asynchronous stream:

> Queries an asynchronous stream for completion status.

I write a simple program to test its behavior on "default stream":

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define cudaSafeCall(call)  \
        do {\
            cudaError_t err = call;\
            if (cudaSuccess != err) \
            {\
                std::cerr << "CUDA error in " << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << "): " \
                    << cudaGetErrorString(err) << '\n';\
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
            }\
        } while(0)

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<20;
  float *x, *d_x;
  x = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

  cudaSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&d_x, N*sizeof(float))); 

  cudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDefault));

  cudaSafeCall(cudaStreamQuery(0));

  cudaSafeCall(cudaFree(d_x));

  free(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Build and run it:

```
$ nvcc sync_test.cu -o sync_test
$ ./sync_test
CUDA error in sync_test.cu(25): device not ready
```

After adding `cudaStreamSynchronize(0);` between `cudaMemcpy` and `cudaStreamQuery`, the error disappeared:

```
cudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDefault));
cudaSafeCall(cudaStreamSynchronize(0));
cudaSafeCall(cudaStreamQuery(0));
```

I am a little confused:
a) `cudaMemcpy()` is synchronous with host code, so after `cudaMemcpy` returned, the copying work in this stream should be done, why does `cudaStreamQuery(0)` return error in first case?
b) If `cudaStreamQuery` only works on asynchronous stream, not default stream, why doesn't `cudaStreamQuery` return error in second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement a) isn't quite accurate for the specific case in your example code:

> a) `cudaMemcpy()` is synchronous with host code, so after `cudaMemcpy` returned, the copying work in this stream should be done,

The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8) for `cudaMemcpy` states:

> This function exhibits [synchronous](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/api-sync-behavior.html#api-sync-behavior__memcpy-sync) behavior for most use cases.

If we click on the [synchronous](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/api-sync-behavior.html#api-sync-behavior__memcpy-sync) link, we are taken to a page that further defines the exact behavior.  You might want to read that whole page, it's not very long.  I'll excerpt two points from the definition of **Synchronous**:

> 2. For transfers from pageable host memory to device memory, a stream sync is performed before the copy is initiated. The function will return once the pageable buffer has been copied to the staging memory for DMA transfer to device memory, **but the DMA to final destination may not have completed**. 
>      (emphasis added)

and:

> 4. For transfers from device to either pageable or pinned host memory, the function returns only once the copy has completed.

Your code fits the first excerpt (item 2. above).  That transfer type (host to device) **can return before the copy is fully completed**.

If you reverse the order of pointers in your `cudaMemcpy` example, thereby reversing the direction of the copy, you will fall into the second excerpt (item 4. above).  In that case, the transfer is guaranteed to be complete, and indeed the error report disappears from your code.

The behavior is possible and accounted for in the documentation.